# Get rid of a duplicate row from SQL table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a reservation table like this

```
place      day       name1     floor1    name2     floor2
---------  --------  --------- --------- --------- ---------
Anaheim    Monday    Sean      3rd       Jenny     2nd
Anaheim    Monday    Jenny     2nd       Sean      3rd
Cerritos   Saturday  Dennis    4th       Sean      3rd
```

As you can see, first and second rows are just duplicate with different order.
I want to have a final table like

```
place      day       name1     floor1    name2     floor2
---------  --------  --------- --------- --------- ---------
Anaheim    Monday    Sean      3rd       Jenny     2nd
Cerritos   Saturday  Dennis    4th       Sean      3rd
```

I was thinking about something like this

```
SELECT t1.place, t1.day, t1.name1, t1.floor, t1.name2, t1.floor2
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE NOT (t1.place = t2.place AND t1.day = t2.day AND
           t1.name1 = t2.name2 AND t1.floor1 = t1.floor2);
```

But this didn't work :( Maybe my understanding is too short..

How should I approach this?

**EDIT**:
Okay, I should have mentioned this, but I'm looking for a general idea, not this table specific.

There could be a table like

```
place      day       name1     floor1    section1   name2    floor2    section2
---------  --------  --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- -----------
Anaheim    Monday    Sean      HR        12         Jenny     QA       24
Anaheim    Monday    Jenny     QA        24         Sean      HR       12
Cerritos   Saturday  Dennis    Main      31         Sean      HR       12
```

In this case, I can't use any of the "sorting" and remove mechanism..

However, thank you all for your effort to solve this!

Comment: what basis are you selecting `name1` as `Sean` and not `Jenny`. based on `max(floor1)` ?

Comment: oh wow so many comments.. I'll read through.. thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to compare `floor1` for more than 9 floors, then `2nd` would be greater than `11th`. To overcome this, you need to extract floor number from `floor1` and then compare it.

Having said that, you can use this query if it is working for your db/version.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo Fast version`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/07328/2)**</kbd>

.

The generic version would be something like this.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo Generic verison`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/07328/1)**</kbd>

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  t1.place,
  t1.day,
  t1.name1
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2
  ON t1.place = t2.place
  AND t1.day = t2.day
  AND CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.floor1, 'st', ''), 'nd', ''), 'rd', ''), 'th', '') AS decimal)
  <=
  CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t2.floor1, 'st', ''), 'nd', ''), 'rd', ''), 'th', '') AS decimal)
GROUP BY t1.place,
         t1.day,
         t1.floor1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) t3
  ON t.place = t3.place
  AND t.day = t3.day
  AND t.name1 = t3.name1
```

Comment: You are selecting non aggregate columns in your query.

Comment: I agree with you, but most modern RDBMS supports that. Else we can only select `place`,`day` and `floor1` to generate count, and use another join on main table on it but it would further slowdown the query. It works fine in MySQL

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : This works for MySQL because it has default behavior to select `min`   values if no aggregate function is used.

Comment: How do you know that the OP is using MySQL?  It is also tagged with SQLite.  In any case, it is always best to keep queries as ANSI compliant as possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Edited my answer for it.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  He should really tag his question rather than leaving us all guessing.

Comment: Yep. My bigger concern was comparing floor number where `11th` is smaller than `3rd`. I just used `replace` to take care of it but we could use `regex` if db/version is confirmed

Comment: Sorry about that. Removed MySQL tag. Also, I actually wanted to get a general approach that can be used widely, not this table specific. Please refer to edited question if you have time. Thank you!

Comment: I already handled it. Please check the fiddle which I mentioned in my answer and let me know if you see any discrepancy.

Comment: Ah this works perfectly fine.. I used the fast (sqlite) version and I actually understand the query now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use a clever `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.place, t1.day, t1.name1, t1.floor, t1.name2, t1.floor2
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.place, t1.day, MAX(t1.floor, t1.floor2) AS floor1,
        MIN(t1.floor, t1.floor2) AS floor2
    FROM table t1, table t2
    GROUP BY t1.place, t1.day, MAX(t1.floor, t1.floor2),
        MIN(t1.floor, t1.floor2)
) t2
ON t1.place = t2.place AND t1.day = t2.day AND t1.floor = t2.floor1 AND
    t1.floor2 = t2.floor2
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, I actually wanted to get a general approach that can be used widely, not this table specific. Please refer to edited question if you have time. Thank you!

Comment: oh, I should try. But what does your MAX() and MIN() doing in their? I don't understand how they are used in general cases

Comment: `MAX(col1, col2)` will always take the column which is alphabetically last, and `MIN(col1, col2)` will take the column which is alphabetically first.  Try the query and you will see this.

Answer (score 0):

Get Sorted names and floor by using functions `LEAST` and `GREATEST` and then group data by concatenating place, day ,names and floors columns.

Try out this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY concat(t1.place,t1.day,least(name1,name2),greatest(name1,name2),
                least(floor1,floor2),greatest(floor1,floor2));
```

SQL Fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02fae/10

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, I actually wanted to get a general approach that can be used widely, not this table specific. Please refer to edited question if you have time. Thank you!